# Delete button works on server but not updating UI screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have data object on server db.json running on port 3001/person and I have designed delete button which should delete specific object when clicked. But when I click delete, it deletes from db.json server but UI part doesn't update until and unless I refresh the page.

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import personService from './services/person'

function App() {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    // { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '00000000', id: 1 },
  ]);

  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('');
  const [newNum, setNewNum] = useState('');
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const handleNameInput = (e) => {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleNumberInput = (e) => {
    setNewNum(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const addName = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (persons.some((person) => person.name === newName)) {
      alert(`${newName} already exists`);
      return;
    }
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNum,
      id: persons.length + 1,
    };
    personService.create(nameObject).then(response => {
      setPersons(persons.concat(response.data));
      setNewName('');
      setNewNum('');
    })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    personService.getAll().then(response => {
      setPersons(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  const filteredPersons = persons.filter((person) =>
    person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  const deletePerson = (id) => {
    const personn = { ...persons }
    
    personService.deletee(id, personn)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('deleted', id)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert("ERROR", err)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PHONEBOOK</h1>
      <div>
        Filter shown with: 
        <input onChange={handleSearchTerm} value={searchTerm} />
      </div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <h2>ADD</h2>
          <div>
            name: <input onChange={handleNameInput} value={newName} />
          </div>
          <div>
            number: <input onChange={handleNumberInput} value={newNum} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addName}>
          add
        </button>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <ul>
        {filteredPersons.map((person) => (
          <li key={person.id}>
            {person.name} {person.number} 
            <button onClick={() => deletePerson(person.id)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-fetch your data again:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import personService from './services/person'


function App() {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    // { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '00000000', id: 1 },
  ]);

  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('');
  const [newNum, setNewNum] = useState('');
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const handleNameInput = (e) => {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleNumberInput = (e) => {
    setNewNum(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const addName = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (persons.some((person) => person.name === newName)) {
      alert(`${newName} already exists`);
      return;
    }
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNum,
      id: persons.length + 1,
    };
    personService.create(nameObject).then(response=>{
        setPersons(persons.concat(response.data));
    setNewName('');
    setNewNum('');
    })
    
  };

const getPersonService =()=> {
 personService.getAll().then(response=>{
      setPersons(response.data)
  })
}

  useEffect(()=>{
    getPersonService();
  },[])

  const filteredPersons = persons.filter((person) =>
    person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  const deletePerson=(id)=>{
    const personn={...persons}
    
    personService.deletee(id,personn).then(response=>{
      console.log('deleted',id)
      getPersonService();
    }).catch((err)=>{
      alert("ERROR",err)
      
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PHONEBOOK</h1>
      <div>
        Filter shown with: <input onChange={handleSearchTerm} value={searchTerm} />
      </div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <h2>ADD</h2>
          <div>
            name: <input onChange={handleNameInput} value={newName} />
          </div>
          <div>
            number: <input onChange={handleNumberInput} value={newNum} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addName}>
          add
        </button>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <ul>
        {filteredPersons.map((person) => (
          <li key={person.id}>
            {person.name} {person.number} <button onClick={()=>deletePerson(person.id)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an item using the delete API, it only updates the server's database. To reflect this change in the UI, you need to make an additional GET request to fetch the updated data from the server and then update the state in your React application. This ensures that the UI stays synchronized with the server data without requiring a full page refresh.

```
const getData =()=> {
 personService.getAll().then(response=>{
      setPersons(response.data)
  })
}

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
  },[])

  const filteredPersons = persons.filter((person) =>
    person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  const deletePerson=(id)=>{
    const personn={...persons}
    personService.deletee(id,personn).then(response=>{
      console.log('deleted',id)
      getData();
    }).catch((err)=>{
      alert("ERROR",err)
      
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

When you call your service code to remove a person, this obviously only makes the change to the backend database. The `App` component's `persons` state is left intact, unchanged. When you reload the page, the `useEffect` hook runs again and fetches all the person data from the DB.

## Solution

Similar to the way the `addName` callback handler makes the API/service call ***then*** enqueues a state update to add the new data to the `persons` state:

```js
const addName = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (persons.some((person) => person.name === newName)) {
    alert(`${newName} already exists`);
    return;
  }

  const nameObject = {
    name: newName,
    number: newNum,
    id: persons.length + 1,
  };

  personService.create(nameObject)
    .then(response => {
      // Creation success, add to local state
      setPersons(persons => persons.concat(response.data));

      setNewName('');
      setNewNum('');
    });
};
```

So too should the `deletePerson` callback handler enqueue a state update to the `persons` state to remove, e.g. filter, the person object by the passed `id` value.

```js
const deletePerson = (id) => {
  personService.deletee(id, persons.slice())
    .then(response => {
      // Delete success, remove from local state
      setPersons(persons => persons.filter(person => person.id !== id));
    }).catch((err) => {
      alert("ERROR", err);
    });
};
```